# How to get an employee permissions in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I have an application that accesses Prestashop backend and database to which I use the internal prestashop employee credentials to login.

So far I can get the employee with:

```
Context::getContext()->employee
```

and check if he is already logged in with:

```
Context::getContext()->employee->isLoggedBack()
```

From there I can access the profile with:

```
Context::getContext()->employee->id_profile
```

but I need to know what are the access rights of the logged in employee so to allow access from my application or not.

I could do that by checking directly on the database but I was wondering if there are any ready made Prestashop core function(s) from which I can test for access rights for a specific employee.

Comment: So far I see that Prestashop provides the Profile class from which someone can access permissions on per id_profile basis:
`function getProfileAccess($id_profile, $id_tab)`

The id_profile for the employee can be access from
`Context::getContext()->employee->id_profile`
for the logged-in employee.

$id_tab parameter that can be passed as:
`Tab::getIdFromClassName('AdminProducts')` or
`Tab::getIdFromClassName('AdminOrders')`
Could not find any reference on the class parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the profile accesses with the following method of the class "Profile"

```
Profile::getProfileAccesses($id_profile, $type);
```

$type can be "id_tab" or "class_name".

Additionally you can get the permissions for a tab with the following method:

```
Profile::getProfileAccess($id_profile, $id_tab);
```

Hope that helps you.